# java: convert a string to a string that contains the hex number of each character

Tags: java, hex

I have a string that actually each byte in it is a representation of a hexadecimal number.

I want to create a new string that contains the actual hexadecimal numbers of each character.

I know that i can do `String.getBytes()` to get the bytes of each character, i know iterate through it with `i=0;i<=String.getBytes().length`. what i don't understand is how to create a new string that each character is the hexacdecimal number (0-F).

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- commons-codec has `Hex.encode(byteArray)`
- you can also use `Integer.toHexString(..)` for each byte

Just be careful when obtaining the bytes. Use the method `getBytes(ecnoding)` instead of the one without arguments which takes the platform encoding.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like

```
String test = "hello world", result = "";

for (byte b : test.getBytes())
    result += Integer.toHexString(b) + " ";

System.out.println(result);

// result = 68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64
```

Keep in mind though, that strings in Java are in unicode.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few misconceptions - or at least problematic descriptions - in your post:

- Strings consist of *characters*, not bytes
- Numbers aren't hexadecimal or decimal etc; their *representations* are hex etc

You're then calling `String.getBytes()`, but it's not clear what encoding you want to use. As stated before, a String is a sequence of *characters*. To convert that into *bytes*, you need to apply an encoding. Unfortunately, `String.getBytes()` uses the "platform default encoding" which is almost *never* a good choice. You should always specify which encoding you want to use.

When you *have* converted the String into bytes (if you definitely want to do that) it's easy to convert that to hex:

```
for (byte b : test.getBytes("UTF-8"))
{
    int x = b & 0xff; // I suspect you don't want negative numbers
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b));
}
```

Alternatively you might want to convert each Unicode *character* to its hex representation:

```
for (char c : test.toCharArray())
{
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(c));
}
```

Note that `Integer.toHexString` doesn't pad its output to a particular number of characters.

If you could give more information about your input and expected output, that would really help.

Comment: i do not want to use System.out.println

Comment: @ufk: That was just an example. As I said, if you can give more detail about what you're really trying to achieve, we can give you a better answer.

Comment: hi! thanks for the assistance. in general what i wanted is to convert each byte to it's hex representation. in general what i wanted is what Hex.encodeHexString() does in the answer that Bozho provided.

Comment: @ufk: A string isn't comprised of bytes though - it's comprised of characters. It's really important that you understand the difference.